# SQL Graph: List alls paths from root, reaching objects of various types

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a product parts hierarchy:

```
Car -> BodyWork
 |
 V
Wheel -> Tyre
```

And certain parts having their supplier info

```
Car -> Tesla
Tyre -> Continental
```

How do you list all paths leading to parts and possibly suppliers ? There should also be specific columns for the reached part or supplier, possibly containing NULL values.

Imagine a road, leading to different kind of things (parts, suppliers), and the query would return all reached things, listing paths, and returning objects of different types into different columns that are set to NULL otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    ProductID int not null identity primary key,
    ProductName varchar(50) 
) AS Node;

INSERT INTO PRODUCT(ProductName) VALUES ('Car'),('BodyWork'),('Wheel'),('Tyre');

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIER (
    SuppierID int not null identity primary key,
    SupplierName varchar(50)    
) AS Node;

INSERT INTO SUPPLIER(SupplierName) VALUES ('Continental'),('Tesla');

CREATE TABLE HAS_PART AS EDGE;

INSERT INTO HAS_PART ($from_id, $to_id)
VALUES ((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Car'), (SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='BodyWork'))
,((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Car'), (SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Wheel'))
,((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Wheel'), (SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Tyre'));

CREATE TABLE SUPPLIED_BY AS EDGE;

INSERT INTO SUPPLIED_BY ($from_id, $to_id)
VALUES ((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Car'), (SELECT $node_id FROM SUPPLIER WHERE SupplierName='Tesla'))
,((SELECT $node_id FROM PRODUCT WHERE ProductName='Tyre'), (SELECT $node_id FROM SUPPLIER WHERE SupplierName='Continental'));

SELECT * FROM HAS_PART;
SELECT * FROM SUPPLIED_BY;

CREATE VIEW All_nodes AS
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, NULL AS SupplierID, NULL AS SupplierName, ProductName AS NodeName FROM PRODUCT
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, SuppierID, SupplierName , SupplierName AS NodeName FROM SUPPLIER;

CREATE VIEW All_edges AS
SELECT * FROM HAS_PART
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM SUPPLIED_BY;

SELECT
       P1.ProductID,
       P1.ProductName,
       COUNT(P2.NodeName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Depth],
       STRING_AGG(P2.NodeName,'->') WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Assembly],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.ProductID) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Product ID],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.SupplierID) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Supplier ID],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.ProductName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Product Name],
       LAST_VALUE(P2.SupplierName) WITHIN GROUP (GRAPH PATH) AS [Final Supplier Name]
FROM
       All_nodes P1,
       All_nodes FOR PATH P2,
       All_edges FOR PATH HP
WHERE MATCH(SHORTEST_PATH(P1(-(HP)->P2)+))
AND P1.ProductID = 1
ORDER BY P1.ProductID;
```

[image]

Comment: Bud you should have edited your question and suggest that this is the work you have done around this. Instead of posting it as an answer. And hence someone has down voted your answer. Oh and you also need to put some sample data. Since you have posted an EXPECTED OUTPUT.